# How do I return absolute path names for files using Perl glob?

Tags: perl, glob

I have some Perl code which has file glob operation.

```
$file1 = @ARGV[0];
@res1 = glob "$file1*";
```

I want the whole absolute paths to be reflected when i glob the files, not just the file names which is the case currently in my code.

e.g. when I do glob "*.pdf" i need the absolute paths of the pdf files to be matched and returned to my array variable by glob.

I tried using module use File::Basename;
but that seems to be used for parsing a file path into directory, file name , suffix.

How do I get this effect.

thanks,

-AD.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to use the core module `Cwd` to get the full path with respect to your current working directory.

```
use Cwd;
@res1 = map { Cwd::abs_path($_) } glob "$file1*";
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. worked nicely, also i learnt about the module Cwd.

Comment: what is there to choose between this and File::Spec rel2abs()

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the standard module `File::Spec`.  It has a sub, `rel2abs()` which is exactly what you want.  See `perldoc File::Spec` for details.  Also, see `perldoc perlmodlib` for the list of standard modules and pragmatics that are install along with Perl.